# Unable to get host headers passed in nginx configuration

Tags: ssl, nginx, hostheaders

I am trying to set up a load-balanced, SSL-based RESTful system utilizing nginx as the frontend (backends use http). I am having a problem getting the full URL path and one argument through to my application.

I have this in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default:

```
upstream backend {
  server 10.200.40.100;
  server 10.200.40.101;
}

server {
  listen  443;
  server_name localhost;
  ssl  on;
  ssl_certificate  /etc/ssl/certs/reverse_chained_star_comtex_com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/certs/star_comtex_com.key;
  ssl_session_timeout  5m;
  ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
  ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

underscores_in_headers on;
ignore_invalid_headers on;

location / {
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_pass http://backend?$args;
}
```

But when I send a request and view the apache2 access log on the backends I see:

```
10.200.40.102 - - [03/Jul/2013:11:51:50 -0400] "GET /? HTTP/1.0" 401 478 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36"
```

I should be seeing something like this:

```
10.200.40.102 - - [02/Jul/2013:11:41:32 -0400] "GET /news/headlines/since/2013-07-02+01:00:00?api_key='xxxxxxx' HTTP/1.1" 401 4889 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36"
```

I do have an underscore in my argument's name, which is why I'm using underscores_in_headers. Any ideas what may be going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried just using `proxy_pass http://backend;`? The get arguments get passed automatically

Comment: I just tried it without the ?$args and now I see this in access.log: `10.200.40.102 - - [08/Jul/2013:13:37:36 -0400] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 401 478 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36"` Not sure if that is progress or not.

Answer (score 0):

you may change
proxy_pass http://backend?$args;
to
proxy_pass http://backend;

will fix this problem